# realloc and the ghosts of mallocs past

Tags: c, free, realloc

I know that `realloc` will free memory when necessary, and I know the third rule of C - "for every `malloc` there must be an equal and opposite `free`"... but how do these two work together?

The situation is best described in code:

```
int main()
{
    myStruct **myStructArray;
    int      i, num_elements;

    num_elements = getnumber(); // gets value for num_elements

    myStructArray = (myStruct **) malloc(num_elements * sizeof(myStruct*));
    for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
        myStructArray[i] = (myStruct *) malloc(sizeof(myStruct));

    // so far so good...

    num_elements = getnumber(); // gets new, LOWER value

    myStructArray = realloc(myStructArrary, num_elements * sizeof(myStruct*));

    // rest_of_code, and necessary free loop for myStructArray etc...
}
```

Obviously the above is nothing more than a snippet, but a snippet paints a thousand words.

Would this create a memory leak? I know the call to `realloc` will free the pointers' memory, but I can see arguments for and against the possibility that there is still going to be a bunch of memory forgotten about.

A leak can be circumvented by incorporating `int number_elements_new` into the code and loop `free`-ing the surplus `myStruct`s before calling `realloc` to free the (now NULL) pointers.

If `realloc` does the donkeywork and frees up ALL the associated memory that's great, otherwise I've got to trawl through to make sure nothing has been missed - `myStruct` itself contains allocated memory and so on.

Thank you for your recommendations...

Comment: I don't see what you mean here. Are you asking if `realloc()` will free the pointers that the array you `malloc()`ed too, and not just its argument? Because then no, it doesn't.

Comment: How do you imagine that it wouldn't leak memory? You still need to free the elements you allocated regardless of if they are in an array or not.

Comment: Please don't [cast the return value of `malloc()` and `realloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: `realloc` doesn't count in the rule, since it takes an existing `malloc`-ed pointer and returns a new one, while freeing up any memory in the event of a reallocation.

Comment: @unwind: force of habit from too much c++, my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're shrinking the size of your array, you would first need to `free` each `myStructArray[i]`  where `i` >= `num_elements`, otherwise you will have a memory leak.

Put another way, shrinking the size of the pointer array does not affect the memory that each array element was pointing to.

Also, in the `realloc` call, you will want to assign the result to a temporary pointer; if `realloc` cannot extend or shrink the buffer, it will return NULL, and you'll lose your reference to that block, which will also introduce a leak:

```
myStruct **tmp = realloc(myStructArray, ...);
if (tmp)
{
  myStructArray = tmp;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`malloc`, `realloc` and `free` have no idea about what the memory is being used for.  If you're using the memory to store pointers to other dynamically-allocated memory, then that's for you to tidy up!

---

Also, note that the way you're using `realloc` in your code snippet is potentially unsafe.  If `realloc` fails, it leaves the original memory un-freed, and returns `NULL`.  Best practice is to assign the return value to a temporary pointer, and then check.  See e.g. http://www.c-faq.com/malloc/realloc.html.

Comment: Suggestion: moreover, no type of malloc allocation tracks pointers stored in that memory; they *always* have to be freed.

Answer (score 0):

If the number is lower than the existing number of elements, you will introduce a memory leak as the reallocated block is not related to the content and you are losing your reference to the blocks allocated in the for-loop.

Therefore you'll have to loop through your array and free all elements that will be subject to removed.

If the number is higher than the existing number, it won't create a memory leak as realloc copies the existing data if a new memory block has been allocated. Therefore your other dynamically allocated blocks (malloc in the for loop) are still referenced by the resized array. The only gotcha here is, that the newly allocated array spaces are uninitialized and can therefore contain invalid pointers.